# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Invalid column name 'e'." | Error with Database

Tags: c#, database, windows-forms-designer

Im using Database Data for my Project and when I type a letter in Textbox1, the application crashes with the error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Invalid column name 'e'."

Database name is Table with "Id" and "altitudes"
Id is a varchar and altitudes is a nchar.

Thats how I want it to work:
Typing a Name in name.Text, search for the name in the database and paste the assigned altitude in altitude.Text.
Altitudes are numbers, Names are Letters in the database.

Where's the error in my code? (Data Source is on purpose blank)

```
        {
            String source = @"Data Source=";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
            con.Open();

            String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID ="+char.Parse(name.Text);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                altitude.Text = (dr["altitudes"].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You’re not surrounding the parameter value with quotes - but don’t just fix that, use a SqlParameter instead.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't tie to the error you indicate.

Comment: Print the value in sqlSelectQuery variable.
Then try to execute the select statement in database.
You can figure out the error.

Comment: It does, it's working with int, but not with char. It's the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never concatenate inputs to create SQL. It is horribly brittle, and susceptible to SQL injection, and i18n/l10n problems (formatting of values). Lots of bad things.

The solution should always be: parameters.

For example:

```cs
const string sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID = @id";
using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", name.Text);
// Etc
```

Or more easily with a tool like Dapper:

```cs
var alt = con.QuerySingleOrDefault<string>(
    "SELECT altitudes FROM [Table] WHERE ID = @id",
    new { id = name.Text });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer, could you show me how to change it in my code? Regards